# Infinite whitespace under my webpage content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For some reasons one of my webpage can be scrolled down infinitely. My html/php is rather big so I don't think that should I post; I really can't find an answer online.

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#content{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#54B0D9;
}

table{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-weight: 400;

}

table, td, tr, th{

    border-style:solid;

    border-color:#E6E7F1;

    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
}

td{
    text-align:center;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

td.count{
    min-width:50px;
}

td.count a{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:block;
}

td.delete{
    min-width:50px;
}

td.delete a{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

td.name{
    min-width:300px;
}

td.name a{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:block;
}

td.efect{
    min-width:150px;
}

td.efect a{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:block;
}

.boldedShitForPykw{
    font-weight: 700;
}

tr.even{
    background-color:#F6F7FA;
}

tr.odd{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.table-container{
    padding-top:30px;
    background-color:#54B0D9;
}
```

I have a fixed navbar at the bottom, could that be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. :) Please try to build an minimal example which reproduces the problem, else it'll be hard to track the issue down. You can use the Stack Snippet or e.g. jsFiddle to provide the example.

Comment: Hello, here is the example http://jailbreakgo.ro/gangprofile.php?gangid=7

Comment: if you scroll down aggresively, it keep scrolling down, might need to zoom in, so you have something to scroll (im on a laptop)

Comment: in your head section you should add this to help make it responsive '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'

Comment: The problem is the div  with id tops. if the page when you scroll your js continue to increase css bottom value.

Comment: ok, I added that, thanks I'll keep that in mind for future projects. But I still can't figure out what's with that infinite scrolling bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by updating your `CSS` from

```
#content {
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative; 
   background-color: #54B0D9;
}
```

to:

```
#content {
   min-height: 100%;
   background-color: #54B0D9;
}
```

*I was able to solve this by using Chrome's Developer Tools to amend the elements styles - this may come in handy next time!*

Comment: thanks, it works :) weird thing, cause I had the same on other pages and they seem to work fine

Comment: @angeldarkland _No problem!_ Glad I was able to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
```

then add media queries to make it responsive, add all of this to the end of you main css sheet

```css
/*
  Based on:
  1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
  2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {

}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {

}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {

}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {

}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* HTC One portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* HTC One portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* HTC One landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/*
  iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
  If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
  (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
  or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
*/

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/*
  iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
  If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
  for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
  like a charm in your responsive design!
*/

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
@media
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Laptops non-retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Laptops retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {

}

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}

/* Moto 360 Watch */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure all them lines of code are necessary for this simple issue.